# MonkeyTalk and Flex

Tags: apache-flex, air, flex-monkey

I'm trying to set up MonkeyTalk with an AIR app and the documentation says it'll work but the tutorial shows no way and I can't figure it out.

Has anyone done this before?

Any tips at all are greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What is MonkeyTalk?  What documentation are you reading?  What have you tried; and why isn't it working?

Comment: MonkeyTalk is the latest version of FlexMonkey; a UI automation tool. I've tried adding the SWC and compiler args to my Flex project and running MonkeyTalk but the connection fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like AIR is not currently supported in MonkeyTalk. Check out this forum post:
[MonkeyTalk support for Air application?](https://www.gorillalogic.com/content/monkeytalk-support-air-application)

Comment: It also says that they don't support mobile on their [FAQ](https://www.gorillalogic.com/monkeytalk-documentation/monkeytalk-faq) page.